# GitLab docker cannot fork "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: docker, gitlab, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to run a **gitlab-ce** docker container on a ubuntu server *version 22.04*.

The log output of `docker logs --follow gitlab` results in

```
execute[/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl start alertmanager] action run
    [execute] /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

even though I have enough memory available by monitoring with `htop`. Docker exited with an error code 137. My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like

```
version: "3.7"
    gitlab:
        image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
        container_name: gitlab
        restart: "no"
        ports:
            - "8929:8929"
            - "2289:22"
        hostname: "gitlab.example.com"
        environment:
            GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
                external_url "https://gitlab.example.com"
                nginx['listen_port'] = 8929
                nginx['listen_https'] = false
                gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2289
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
            - ./volumes/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
            - ./volumes/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
        shm_size: "256m"
```

I am using docker version 20.10.16. Other images work fine with docker. The output of `ulimit -a` is

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029348
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: 137 indicate that not enough memory, have you check the system memory size? @phil98

Comment: Yes. As stated in the question, I have enough memory available. **However**, the instance is running on a vserver.

Comment: try to increase the shm_size? @phil98 what is the ulimit -a output?

Comment: try to using this command to check the oom: journalctl -k | grep -i -e memory -e oom @phil98

Comment: @Dolphin Increasing shm_size does not help. I update the question for the output of `ulimit`.

Comment: Using `journalctl -k` gives no output. Maybe the provider prevents this.

Comment: Try to increase the open files. @phil98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a vServer which looks pretty much like your machine.

I guess that the problem is a limit on the processes that can run at the same time. Probably you are limited by 400 but you need more to run your compose network.

```
cat /proc/user_beancounters | grep numproc
```

The response is formatted like this: `held, maxheld, barrier, limit`

If you run this command, you should be able to see that you are very close to exceeding the limit (if I'm right with my assumption).

Checkout this link, they talk about Java, but the general problem is the same:
https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=180774

Comment: This makes sense. I upgraded my vserver and the issue was gone. With that I am running 617 processes. Thanks for sharing!